# is it safe to use domain module of npm for exception handling in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I want to catch exception occurred in callback function of nodeJS. Is it safe to use domain npm module for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to this: [nodejs domain](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html), I guess as long as they are registered to the domain instance, you can use them.

A better idea would be simply to do something like this:

```
callback(new Error('something bad happened'));
```